# Identifying scanned QR code using Google Mobile Vision API

Tags: android, qr-code, google-vision

I am using Google Mobile Vision Api for scanning barcodes and that works pretty fast. But now I want to identify barcodes whether they are for Wifi, Contact, SMS or something else.

I've tried a way of my own to recognize the type of barcode scanned but that is using some If-else. So, is there a way I can directly identify the type of barcode scanned?

Like in [Zxing Wiki](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Barcode-Contents#user-content-contact-information) there is an option for every type of barcode. But I didn't find any for the google mobile vision api.

Here's the code I'm using:
1. Passing the rawValue to another activity

```
@Override
    public void onRetrieved(final Barcode barcode) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               Intent intent = new Intent(QRScanner.this, BarcodeResult.class);
               intent.putExtra("Barcode", barcode.rawValue);
               QRScanner.this.finish();
               startActivity(intent);
           }
       });
```

2. Identifying the barcode

```
        textView1 = intent.getStringExtra("Barcode");
        if(textView1.startsWith("BEGIN:VCARD")) {
            VCard vcard = Ezvcard.parse(textView1).first();
            String str = ""+vcard.getFormattedName().getValue();
            String no = "";
            List<Telephone> list = vcard.getTelephoneNumbers();
            if(list.size()>1){

                for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
                    no = ""+list.get(i)+"\n"+no;
            }
            else if(list.size()==1) {
                no = list.get(0).toString();
            }
            if(!no.equals(""))
               str = str+"\n"+no;
            textView.setText(str);
        }
```

This code works well and identify a VCard barcode but adding a If-else for every type of barcode is a problem and will take time. Hence, if there's a solution I'm missing, please share.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`barcode.valueFormat`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/barcode/Barcode.html#public-int-valueformat) variable to identify it. After passing this value to another activity, you can do something like this:

```
if(valueFormart == Barcode.CONTACT_INFO){
   VCard vcard = Ezvcard.parse(textView1).first();
   ...
}
```